# mysql, set value of column "id"(auto increment ) as an default value for column B

Tags: mysql, default

I am designing a message system.

In the table where I store the messages, the `message_id` column is auto increment.

I have another column `message_reference_id`.
I want its default value to be `message_id`.

How do I set this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the default value to the value in another column. Instead if your column is NOT NULL, you could change it to nullable and set the default value to NULL. Then when you select it, use this:

```
SELECT IFNULL(message_reference_id, message_id) AS message_reference_id
FROM your_table
```

You could even put this in a view.

Alternatively you can create a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) which updates the value on insert.

Comment: while i am selecting, i am doing group by message_reference_id. so i cannot do as above. all the messages with same  message_reference_id are considered as a group(i mean there are replys) and parent message will have message_id equal to message_reference_id

Comment: @aparna: Change `GROUP BY message_reference_id` to `GROUP BY IFNULL(message_reference_id, message_id)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `NULL` instead and, on access, use [`COALESCE(message_reference_id, message_id)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce).

This gives you `message_reference_id` in the general case. However, if it is `NULL`, you get `message_id` instead.

EDIT: With this knowledge, you can work with inner and outer queries - e.g. use the `COALESCE` trick in the inner query and the `GROUP BY` in the outer one.

But I don't know how well this performs, as the `GROUP BY` would probably like to use indexes, which cannot be provided this way.

Comment: while i am selecting, i am doing group by message_reference_id. so i cannot do as above. all the messages with same message_reference_id are considered as a group(i mean there are replys) and parent message will have message_id equal to message_reference_id